# Determine where a function was executed?

Tags: python

how should I define a function, `where`,which can tell where it was executed, with no arguments passed in?
all files in ~/app/

a.py:

```
def where():
    return 'the file name where the function was executed'
```

b.py:

```
from a import where
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print where() # I want where() to return '~/app/b.py' like __file__ in b.py
```

c.py:

```
from a import where
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print where() # I want where() to return '~/app/c.py' like __file__ in c.py
```

Comment: As you note, you already have the information you want as `__file__`. Why do you need to write a function to return it?

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: @kindall  I want where() know where it is executed, and use it as a varible in its function body.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look up the call stack by using [`inspect.stack()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

```
from inspect import stack

def where():
    caller_frame = stack()[1]
    return caller_frame[0].f_globals.get('__file__', None)
```

or even:

```
def where():
    caller_frame = stack()[1]
    return caller_frame[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`traceback.extract_stack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html):

```
import traceback
def where():
    return traceback.extract_stack()[-2][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.argv[0]
```

sys.argv[0] is always the name/path of the file running, even with no arguments passed in

Answer (score 0):

Based on this...

```
print where() # I want where() to return '~/app/b.py' like __file__ in b.py
```

...it sounds more like what you want is the qualified path of the script you're executing.

In which case, try...

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__)))
```

Using `realpath()` should cope with the case where you're running the script from a symbolic link.